# How to Rename Two Tables in One Atomic Operation in MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I've built up a new temporary table with updated data and I want to replace the existing reference table with the new temporary one. In MS SQL Server how can I do this atomically so the reference table is never invalid to other processes accessing the DB.

(Similar question for My SQL: [How to rename two tables in one atomic operation in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34391759/how-to-rename-two-tables-in-one-atomic-operation-in-mysql) )

Comment: Just use a transaction. Other processes will be blocked until the operation is finished.

Comment: This a link to the doc about renaming tables in ms server [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/rename-tables-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: "Use a transaction" - obvious when you say it out loud :)  Thanks

Comment: Another option could be view on top of table. And single `ALTER VIEW constant_name AS SELECT ... FROM new_tab_name`

Comment: `ALTER TABLE ... SWITCH` is a very cool feature and does not need Enterprise Edition see https://stackoverflow.com/a/66429140/14868997 at no point are any tables non-existent

Answer (score 1):

**If the temporary table is *exactly* the same, you can use partition-switching.**

You do not need Enterprise Edition, nor do the tables need to be partitioned.

The tables need to have the **same** column definitions (including precision/lengths/collation), same clustered *and* non-clustered indexes, and most importantly, the same filegroup, therefore **they cannot be temp tables or table variables**.

This technique is extremely fast, and will not cause missing-object errors to others querying the table.

```sql
SET XACT_ABORT, NOCOUNT ON;      -- force immediate rollback if session is killed

BEGIN TRAN;

TRUNCATE TABLE myTargetTable;    -- target must be empty

ALTER TABLE myStaging SWITCH TO myTargetTable
WITH (WAIT_AT_LOW_PRIORITY (MAX_DURATION = 1 MINUTES, ABORT_AFTER_WAIT = BLOCKERS));

-- not strictly necessary to use WAIT_AT_LOW_PRIORITY but better for blocking
-- use SELF instead of BLOCKERS to kill your own session

-- Set MAX_DURATION to 0 to force blockers off immediately

COMMIT TRAN;
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66429140/14868997) for further details

Answer (score 0):

For reference here's the solution I derived from @Alejandro's comment above:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
DROP TABLE ReferenceData
EXEC sp_rename 'NewReferenceData', 'ReferenceData'
COMMIT
```